# Kubernetes : Mechanism to prevent pod with images on certain clusters

Tags: docker, kubernetes

In our kubernetes cluster setup, we normally have 2 types of setups: `prod` and `dev`. The clusters have tags/labels as well as env variables to identify them as such.

Some of our images are designed to dev but not prod and vice-versa (differences are in the custom binaries that are installed within the org). Right now, when the pods start , they do not fail at startup but are functionally useless because the accurate binaries are missing. Is there a way to prevent a prod pod to not start with an image named dev (and vice-versa)

Answer (score 3):

Kubernetes provides a few ways to enforce your organizational policies, some are as follow:

**using ImagePolicyWebhook:**

You can use `ImagePolicyWebhook` to enforce your image usage policies by doing `ImageReview.` More info [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/admission-controllers/#imagepolicywebhook).

**Using validation webhook:**

A `validation webhook` intercepts the request for pod creation, You can write your business logic in the webhook code, and it will enforce using the admission review. You can find more [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/extensible-admission-controllers/) and [here](https://technekey.com/what-is-validation-webhook-in-kubernetes/).

**Using OPA Gatekeeper:**

Alternatively, you may use `OPA Gatekeeper` for policy enforcement. You can get more info [here](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2019/08/06/opa-gatekeeper-policy-and-governance-for-kubernetes/).

Note that each option listed above are huge topic on its own. You might need to choose the best-suited option for your use case.